# Is It possible to rename hosted service in Windows Azure

Tags: azure

Is It possible to rename hosted service of windows azure? I created it with a wrong name and I want to rename it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems not possible. You might have to remove and recreate.

Comment: This is now possible with the [Azure Powershell SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156055.aspx)...just not via the [Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can relabel the Azure Hosted Cloud Service by using the [Azure Powershell SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/). You just need to download the publish settings before you can execute any [Azure Cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841). Use [`Set-AzureService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152830.aspx) to update the Azure Cloud Service name.

#### Rename Azure Cloud Service.ps1

```cs
import-module Azure

# download publish settings
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile

# import settings you just downloaded
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\MySub-DATE-credentials.publishsettings"

# view subscription details
Get-AzureSubscription

# select active subscription
Select-AzureSubscription 'MySub'

# view cloud services for selected sub
Get-AzureService 

# update cloud service name/description
Set-AzureService 'myServiceName' 'Friendly Service Name' 'Detailed Service Description'
```

Comment: This does allow you to change the service url and description however it does not allow you to change the service name